# css to set width but not exceed table width

Tags: css

I would like the width of an input to be 80% but then not stretch across the screen past 200 px for instance. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't understand. Maybe a picture would help?

Comment: I rephrased to be a bit clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, use `width` and [`max-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS%3amax-width):

```
input {
    width: 80%;
    max-width: 200px
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FTRun/ *(reduce the window width)*